# how can I determine a layer's data source type

Tags: openlayers-3

How can I determine a layer's data source type, e.g. Vector, WMS, Bing, etc. In OpenLayers 2 I used the layer's CLASS_NAME for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use instanceof checks, so e.g. `layer.getSource() instanceof ol.source.TileWMS`